# Is it possible to change the header height of an NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I am saving a PDF from an `NSTextview` and putting a logo in the header. I overrode `pageHeader` and the logo appears but it is clipped.

Is it possible to change the header height of an `NSTextView`?

Thanks!

Partial code:

```
-(IBAction)impLaudo:(id)sender 
{
    NSPrintInfo *printInfo;
    NSPrintInfo *sharedInfo;
    NSPrintOperation *printOp;
    NSMutableDictionary *printInfoDict;
    NSMutableDictionary *sharedDict;

    sharedInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
    sharedDict = [sharedInfo dictionary];
    printInfoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:sharedDict];

    [printInfoDict setObject:NSPrintSaveJob forKey:NSPrintJobDisposition];
    [printInfoDict setObject:[[dirLaudos stringByAppendingString:[estudo stringValue]] stringByAppendingString:@".pdf"] forKey:NSPrintSavePath];

    printInfo = [[NSPrintInfo alloc] initWithDictionary: printInfoDict];
    [printInfo setHorizontalPagination: NSClipPagination];
    [printInfo setVerticalPagination: NSAutoPagination];
    [printInfo setVerticallyCentered:NO];
    [[printInfo dictionary] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSPrintHeaderAndFooter];

    printOp = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:textView printInfo:printInfo];
    [printOp setShowsPrintPanel:NO];
    [printOp runOperation];    
}


@implementation MyTextView 

- (NSAttributedString *)pageHeader
{
    // Adicionando cabeçalho
    NSAttributedString *theHeader = nil;

    NSImage * pic = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[dirLayout stringByAppendingString:@"cabecalho.jpg"]];
    NSTextAttachmentCell *attachmentCell = [[NSTextAttachmentCell alloc] initImageCell:pic];
    NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
    [attachment setAttachmentCell: attachmentCell ];
    theHeader = [NSAttributedString  attributedStringWithAttachment: attachment];
    return theHeader;
}

@end
```

Comment: Please post the code you're using to generate the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding `-pageHeader`, you should override `-drawPageBorderWithSize:`, which allows you to draw additional marks on the page at print time.

The Size parameter is an `NSSize` struct containing the size of the current logical page. All you need to do is draw your logo in the correct location:

```
- (void)drawPageBorderWithSize:(NSSize)pageSize
{
    [super drawPageBorderWithSize:pageSize];
    //draw your logo
    NSPoint offset = NSMakePoint(100.0, 100.0);
    NSImage* logo = [NSImage imageNamed:@"logo"];
    NSSize logoSize = [logo size];
    NSPoint imageOrigin = NSMakePoint(offset.x, pageSize.height - (offset.y + logoSize.height));
    [self lockFocus];
    [logo drawInRect:NSMakeRect(imageOrigin.x, imageOrigin.y, logoSize.width, logoSize.height)
            fromRect:NSZeroRect 
           operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
            fraction:1.0 
      respectFlipped:YES 
               hints:nil];
    [self unlockFocus];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rob-keniger! Code posted. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: That's great. You should mark the question as answered if that's the case.